# Is it possible to have remarks removed/replaced automatically after a period of time?

Tags: support, editing

When writing answers to questions, I sometimes would like to add remarks that get removed or replaced by other remarks automatically after a day or two.

For example with one answer I wished to point out that I just submitted a package to CTAN which should be available via CTAN in a day or two.
After a day or two that remark should be changed to pointing out that there is a package available at CTAN.

Is automatizing such things possible via the web interface of StackExchange or will I have to wait for two days and then log in at StackExchange and edit my answer "by hand"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By 'remarks' you might mean either part of the text of an answer or a comment on an answer. In either case the answer is 'no, there is no automation' but the reasoning is I suppose slightly different. For answers, they are explicitly supposed to be written by someone as dealing with the matter raised in a question. As such, they are quite deliberately never auto-changed. Comments are intended as *not the answer*: they are not searchable, *etc.* There have been questions in various places about some 'auto-cleanup' of comments (which would leave answers unchanged), but this has never been agreed by the network. (Various arguments have been put forward on both sides, from memory.)